# Jackson desrialize date: ignore time/set time to 0

Tags: java, json, spring, date, jackson

Below is my list of json objects:

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2022-04-06T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Date": "2022-12-06T00:00:00"
    }
]
```

and my POJO:

```
@Data
public class MyPojo {

    @JsonProperty("Date")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date date;
}
```

Deserialization code:

```
public <T> List<T> toObjList(String json, Class<T> className) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, className));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Exception converting json to Object: {}", json);
            throw new AppException("Exception while converting String to Object list", ex, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

My problem is, despite omitting the time in `jsonFormat` pattern, I see that some random time is added to each date. I printed the serialized dates and following was the output:

> (date=Fri Sep 30 05:30:00 IST 2022)

I tried parsing a date with simleDateFormat and it seemed to parse excluding the time.

```
String input = "2022-09-30T00:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = parser.parse(input);
System.out.println(date);
```

This gave an expected output

> Fri Sep 30 00:00:00 IST 2022

Comment: Can you use LocalDate?

Comment: My main objective was to compare dates by nullifying time. But that was a dumb idea and has better ways to do that. Now I'm just curious about the behavior.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`; both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). I still more stringly strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s notoriously troublesome and equally outdated.

Comment: `05:30:00 IST` is not *some random time*. It is your offset from UTC. Fri Sep 30 05:30:00 IST 2022 equals Fri Sep 30 00:00:00 UTC 2022. Your real problem is that a `Date` is very far from living up to its name: it cannot hold a date neither with nor without time of day. It’s a point in time, and at that point in time the time of day (and also the date) differ across time zones. So there is no true such thing as setting the time to 00:00:00. The solution is to drop that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The terrible `java.util.Date` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Among the many flaws in that class, the name `Date` is a misnomer. The class represents a moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. So it always has a time of day, plus the offset of zero.

## `java.time.LocalDate`

If you want to represent a date-only value, without time of day, and without offset or time zone, use the modern class [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

## Determining a date from a moment

When handed a `java.util.Date` object, immediately convert to its modern replacement, [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). Use the new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

To determine a date, you must specify a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. “Tomorrow” in `Asia/Tokyo` is simultaneously “yesterday” in `America/Edmonton`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;  // Specify your time zone of interest.
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract your desired date-only value.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Compare `LocalDate` objects using `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter` methods.

Search to learn more. All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: So `java.util.date` is too outdated to use? Wonder why haven't they deprecated it yet.

Comment: I guess the reason why they haven’t officially deprecated it yet is there are still a number of methods in the JDK that require or return a `Date` object. So long as they haven’t upgraded those methods to java.time — which is a major task — they cannot reasonably tell us never to use `Date`. We should still only use it when calling one of those methods and only convert to `Date` right before calling the method.

Comment: What I cannot understand either is why they haven’t put a note in the documentation similar to this one for `StringTokenizer`: *`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. …*

Comment: At least [the official Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) is very clear in that it only shows the use of java.time. The only mention of `Date` is how you convert to and from `Date` when you need to interact with legacy code the way I just described in my first comment.